# NodeJS, Express & MongoDB running script every 24hrs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a web app that uses Express & NodeJS, with MongoDB as the database. I would like to run a script every 24 hours that will run through the database and checking for any accounts that will be expiring and sending them a notification email,  what would the best way to go about this be?

Comment: Investigate [cron](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Comment: cron, setTimeout, some Windows service, some linux Daemon, there are too many answers to give you a complete answer.  Please pick a method and come back if you run into direct issues with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you're running in a *nix environment):

Add an entry to your cron file ([cron man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)) using command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The line should include

```
0   23 *   *   *     node script.js
```

0 indicates to run at the beginning of the hour (minute 0)
23 indicates to run at 11PM hour (hour 23)
*'s indicate any day of week, month, or any month of year

**Note, this will run as root.**  You can use `su` to run the script as a different user [referenced answer](https://serverfault.com/a/352837).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/) package, it does exactly this (and more)